# Similar string pattern is recognized as one and changing column names incorrectly even if I use word boundaries approach

Tags: r, regex

I have a data frame with an specific pattern in its column names:

```
wssgroup_1_norm
wxsgroup_2_norm
wargroup_3_norm
wetgroup_10_norm
wegroup_11_norm
```

I used an approach that recognized the `group_*` (*: any number from 1 to 11) string, then, replace the string with another string.

IMPORTANT: please notice that `group_*` is bind to more text without an underscore in between, like this: `wssgroup_1`.

Here is the code:

```
# Mapping of group names to replacement strings
group_names_l <- list(
  group_1 = "_IgG1", group_2 = "_IgG2", group_3 = "_IgG3", group_4 = "_IgG4",
  group_5 = "_IgA1", group_6 = "_IgM", group_7 = "_FcyR2", group_8 = "_FcyR2b",
  group_9 = "_FcyR3av", group_10 = "_FcyR3b", group_11 = "_C1q"
)

# Replace column names using the group_names_l mapping
colnames(luminex_data_o_v2) <- sapply(colnames(luminex_data_o_v2), function(col) 
{
  for (key in names(group_names_l)) {
    if (grepl(key, col)) {
      return(gsub(key, group_names_l[[key]], col))
    }
  }
  return(col)
})
```

This approach works partially fine, because I realized that the `group 1, 10 and 11` is recognized as one and replaced as `_IgG1` in all three cases. So the new column names are partially correct, and my new df have incorrect column names in the `groups_10 and 11`.

Then, I receive some advice to replace the string using `word boundaries` (from StackOverflow),
one approach was this:

```
gsub(paste0("^", key,"$"), group_names_l[[key]], col))
```

or this:

```
gsub(paste0("\\b", key,"\\b"), group_names_l[[key]], col)
```

However, this two new approach do nothing in my df, are currently not recognizing nothing on my column names.

Questions:

- What can I do to avoid this confusion?
- Why word boundaries is not working properly?
- What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear what is going on when you actually look at the `group_names_l` list:

- Each item starts with a word char `_` (and it is attached on the left to another word char in your data), so no word boundary check is necessary here, on the left side
- Each item also ends with a digit, so you want a *digit boundary* on the right side.

In the end, all you want is to check if there is no digit on the right:

```r
colnames(df) <- sapply(colnames(df), function(col) 
{
  for (key in names(group_names_l)) {
    if (grepl(paste0(key, "(?!\\d)"), col, perl=TRUE)) {
      return(sub(paste0(key, "(?!\\d)"), group_names_l[[key]], col, perl=TRUE))
    }
  }
  return(col)
})
```

I added `perl=TRUE` to both `grep` and `sub` commands since the patterns require a PCRE regex engine.

I replaced `gsub` with `sub` since you expect a single replacement in the string anyway.